# Prove that for each $r>0$, the sequence of function $\{f_n:[-r,r]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}$ is uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a bounded sequence of numbers. For each natural number $n$ and each number $x$, define $$f_n(x)=a_0+a_1x+\frac{a_2x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{a_nx^n}{n!}$$ Prove that for each $r>0$, the sequence of function $\{f_n:[-r,r]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}$ is uniformly convergent.

Proof:

Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded sequence, then for all $n$, there exists an $M$ such that $|a_n|<M$. Since $r>0$, to show the sequence of function $\{f_n:[-r,r]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}$ is uniformly convergent, we have two cases for $n>m\geq N$:

If $|r|<1$, apply the Geometric Sum Formula, we have $$|f_{n}(x)-f_m(x)|=\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{a_kx^k}{k!}\right|\leq\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}a_k\leq\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}M$$

If $|r|\geq1$, we have $$|f_{n}(x)-f_m(x)|=\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{a_kx^k}{k!}\right|\leq\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{Mx^k}{k!}\right|$$

---

I stuck at this step, can someone give me a hint or suggestion to receive the result? Thanks

Comment: You should define $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kx^k/k!$, which is well defined since $\{a_k\}$ is bounded. Then take $\lvert f - f_n \rvert$, and it's pretty easy from there on.

Comment: @Hugo do I need to break into two cases since $r<0$?

Comment: No, there is no need to break! You just have to prove $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} r^k/k!$ tends to zero as $n$ tends to $\infty$, which is quite standard (it is the "tail" of the series for $e^r$).

Comment: (i) " for all $n$ there exists an $M$" should be " there exists an $M$ such that for all $n$." This is a **big** difference. (ii) The two inequalities you write are wrong. You first need to apply the triangle inequality, and then the absolute values are inside the sum. (For instance, in your first inequality, nothing says $a_k$ is even non-negative... so the inequality you wrote cannot hold in general.)

Comment: "for all $n$ there exists $M$..." Careful there. That should read "there exists $M$ such that for all $n$ ..."